# oracle database data synchronized from one to multi relative tables

Tags: oracle

I hava a user table , which is quite simple

```
    create table user (
     user_id int primary key,
     user_name varchar2(20)
    )
```

And I build a couples of relative tables assocaite with user table and each table has a `user_id` , `user_name`.
So here comes a question, I happend misinput a data with wrong name, but then I just linked to this wrong record with all relative tables. If I want correct the `user` table and same time synchronized `user_name` in all relative tables.How I do in  simple way? Plus I didn't set any constraint with these tables.

Edit:

So let me put that more clearly. I can query all user from `user` table, and then I just create a `select` in the jsp page. And this selector got two field `user_id`, `user_name`. This is how we call it a selector. First I recorded a man with '01','tam' maybe, and I just recorded another row in `salary` with 'tam','$1300'. This was all wrong cause name was 'tom'. It's easily to change `user` or `salary` , but in our system, there are over 40 tables linked to `user`. I know it's a bad idea but it is designed that way
by our dba and it already worked a long time.

Comment: Quote: " each table has a user_id , user_name". This is the problem. Related tables should refrerence only with the **primary key**. I.e. the column `user_id`.

Comment: @MarmiteBomber Yeah, you're right, this is definately wrong design.Unfortunately the structure is just there that I can't changed .

Comment: When you say "I didn't set any constraint with these tables." do you mean there are no foreign keys defined? How did you link the `user_name` on all these relative tables?

Comment: @APC I'm using the table in java program and we designed a user selector which could query all users from table. So that's not a problem.

Comment: @APC I mean this is no problem to link the `user_name` cause I got a selector.The true question is when the `user_name` has changed, for example, says I got a 'salary' table already has a 'tam' linked to `user` table but the true name is 'tom', so this is question cause there are maybe 30,40 tables to be updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We'll start by making the problem explicit. The data model violates [Third Normal Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form): instead of relying on `user_id` to reference `user_name` every table dependent on the `user` table has the attribute. The consequence of this is that correcting a mistake in `user_name` means propagating that change to every table.

Further more it seems that this application lacks a mechanism for correcting errors, or rather propagating the correction to all the impacted tables. So, what to do?

Dynamic SQL and the data dictionary to the rescue:

```
declare
    l_id user.user_id%type := 1234;
    l_old_name user.user_name%type := 'Tam';
    l_new_name user.user_name%type := 'Tom';

begin
    for rec in ( select table_name from user_tab_cols where column_name = 'USER_ID'
                 intersect
                 select table_name from user_tab_cols where column_name = 'USER_NAME'
                 )
    loop
        execute immediate 'update '|| rec.table_name ||
                 ' set user_name = :1 where user_id = :2 and user_name = :3'
                 using l_new_name, l_id, l_old_name;
        commit;
    end loop;
end;
/
```

No guarantees about performance, because it depends on the data and indexing for each table.

---

> "it already worked a long time"

Which makes me wonder how many data inconsistencies are contained in your system that you don't know about? Maybe your DBA needs to brush up on their data modelling skills.